# I am not able to fetch the data from browser and add it to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

`

```
import DefaultLayout from "../components/DefaultLayout"
import React, {useEffect,useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { DeleteOutlined , EditOutlined} from "@ant-design/icons"
import { Button ,Form,Input,message,Modal,Table } from "antd";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function Items(){
    const [itemsData , setItemsData] = useState([])
    const [addEditModalVisibility , setAddEditModalVisibility]=useState(false)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const getAllItems = function(){

        dispatch({type: 'showLoading'})

        axios.get('/api/items/get-all-items').then((response)=>{
            dispatch({type: 'hideLoading'})
            setItemsData(response.data)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            dispatch({type: 'hideLoading'})
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'Item',
            dataIndex: 'image',
            render: (image, record) => <img src={image} alt='' height='60' width='60' />
        },
        {
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            title: 'Price',
            dataIndex: 'price'
        },
        {
            title: 'Categories',
            dataIndex: 'categories'
        },
      
        {
            title: 'Actions',
            dataIndex: '_id',
            render: (id, record) => <div className="d-flex">
                <DeleteOutlined className="mx-2"/>
                <EditOutlined className="mx-2"/>
            </div>
        }

    ]

    useEffect(() =>{
        getAllItems()
    }, [])

    const onFinish = (values)=>{
        
        dispatch({type : 'showLoading'})

        axios.post('/api/items/add-item' , values).then((response)=>{
            dispatch({type: 'hideLoading'})
            message.success('Item added successfully')
            setAddEditModalVisibility(false)
            getAllItems()
        }).catch((error)=>{
            dispatch({type: 'hideLoading'})
            message.error('Something went wrong')
            console.log(error)
        })
        
    }
    return(
    <DefaultLayout>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h3>Items</h3>
            <Button type="primary" onClick={()=>setAddEditModalVisibility(true)}>Add Item</Button>
        </div>
        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={itemsData} bordered />

        <Modal onCancel={()=>setAddEditModalVisibility(false)} visible={addEditModalVisibility} title='Add New Item' footer={false}>

            <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>

                <Form.Item name='name' label='Name'>
                    <Input />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name='price' label='Price'>
                    <Input />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item name='image' label='Image-URL'>
                    <Input />
                </Form.Item>

                <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">Save</Button>
                </div>


            </Form>

        </Modal>
    </DefaultLayout>
    )
}

export default Items;
```

Here i have used axios.post method inorder to add an item into mongoDB compass.

```
const express = require("express");
const ItemModel = require("../models/itemsModel")
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/get-all-items" , async function(req , res){
    try {
        const items = await ItemModel.find();
        res.send(items);
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json(error)
    }
    
})

router.post("/add-item" , async function(req , res){
    try {
        const newitem = new ItemModel(req.body)
        await newitem.save()
        res.send('Item added successfully')
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json(error)
    }
    
})

module.exports = router
```

This is the code for itemRoute.js.

`

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    cartItems: []
}
export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case "addToCart": return {
            ...state,
            cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload]
        }
        case "deleteFromCart": return {
            ...state,
            cartItems : [...state.cartItems.filter((item)=>item._id !== action.payload._id)]
        }
        case "updateCart": return {
            ...state,
            cartItems: state.cartItems.map((item) => item._id == action.payload._id ? { ...item, quantity: action.payload.quantity } : item),
        };
        case "showLoading" : return{
            ...state,
            loading: true
        }
        case "hideLoading" : return{
            ...state,
            loading : false
        }
        


        default: return state
    }
}
```

This is the Rootreducer code. `

And the code for dbConnect.js and ItemModel.js is:
`

So i tried to add an item in the browser usin the axios.post method but it is showing the message something went wrong and shows the axios error in the console. Please help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add data to MongoDB, you need to use a MongoDB driver. You can use the Mongoose driver which is a Node.js package that provides a simple API to interact with MongoDB. You can use the Mongoose API to create, read, update, and delete data from MongoDB.

Once you have installed the Mongoose driver, you can use the following code instead to add data to MongoDB:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/items');

// Create a schema for the items
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    image: String,
    categories: [String]
});

// Create a model for the items
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

// Create a new item
const newItem = new Item({
    name: 'item name',
    price: 'item price',
    image: 'item image',
    categories: ['item category']
});

// Save the new item to the database
newItem.save();
```

Comment: I have done it in this way. Firstly i have created dbConnect.js file and the code is..        const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const URL = "mongodb+srv://simaad:Syed2000@cluster0.mwtbdqx.mongodb.net/SI-Pos"

mongoose.connect(URL)

let connectionobj = mongoose.connection

connectionobj.on("connected", function(){
    console.log("MongoDb connection successfull!")
})

connectionobj.on("error", function(){
    console.log("MongoDb connection Failed")
})

Comment: Also i have done the above thing that you have sent in this way   `const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true }
}, {timestamps : true})

const itemsModel = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema)

module.exports = itemsModel`

Comment: How to fix this please help..